# JQuery DateTimePicker - not obeying hourMin option

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a page which has two date and time pickers, one for a start and one for an end date (the end date is set by the start date, so you can effectively select a date earlier).  I have `hourMin` and `hourMax` but as much as the code obeys the fact these exist, you are still able to move the slider backwards before 08:00!  I can't figure out just what's going wrong here.  Here's my working code (but is able to change < 08:00).

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#startdate');
var endDateTextBox = $('#enddate');

$.timepicker.datetimeRange(
    startDateTextBox,
    endDateTextBox,
    {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm",
        hourMin: 8,
        hourMax: 20,        
        stepHour: 1,
        stepMinute: 15,             
        minDate: new Date(moment().add(1, 'days').format("YYYY, MM, DD")),
        minTime: "8",
        start: {
            onClose: function(date) {
                if ($('#startdate').val().length > 0) {
                    $.post('checkdate.asp',{
                        startdate : moment($('#startdate').datepicker( 'getDate' )).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
                        },
                        function(data) {
                            if (data == "1") {
                                $('#msgBox').html('Due to the lateness of such a request, no booking can be guaranteed.')
                                $('#msgBox').dialog('open')
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }, // start picker options
        end: {} // end picker options                   
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, an alternative setting is:

```
minTime: '8:00 am',
maxTime: '8:00 pm'
```

Which works beautifully!